# Cant retriev bcrypt hash from mongodb with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, bcrypt

Im developing an app with rails and mongodb. It has an authentication system but isn't working at all. After a while i figured why.
If i do:

```
<% user = User.where(:email => 'test@test.com').first %>
<%= user.hash %> | <%= user.salt %>
```

It returns:

```
287708835 | $2a$10$Arn.fJ0QT3zKRE748wNbXO
```

But if i do "the same" on mongo

```
db.users.find({'email' => 'test@test.com'})
```

It returns:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5103834b108f67f3e9000005"), "email" : "test@test.com", "salt" : "$2a$10$Arn.fJ0QT3zKRE748wNbXO", "hash" : "$2a$10$Arn.fJ0QT3zKRE748wNbXOYBI7k54x6HKypo0m4LyUrvERpTKygSe" }
```

So i can retrieve the salt without problems but not the hash.

Im using bcrypt-ruby to generate the salt and the hash

```
BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
```

How can i get the real hash from the db?

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.hash` calls [Object#hash](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/hash) method not your attribute method. I think you have two options:

1. call it in other way (not sure what ORM are you using but something
   like `user.read_attribute('hash')` might work)
2. rename your field